# Tuareg-mode can't find ocaml?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I have tuareg-mode working on emacs. I downloaded ocaml 4.01.0 on my Mac OS and installed it.

```
Maxs-MacBook-Pro:~ Max$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

Maxs-MacBook-Pro:~ Max$ which ocamlrun
/usr/local/bin/ocamlrun
```

When in tuareg-mode, C-x C-b ocaml returns "Searching for program: No such file or directory, ocaml"

What do I need to do to get ocaml to work with tuareg-mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `/usr/local/bin` may be in `$PATH` for your shell, Emacs may not have the correct value set for `$PATH`

Try adding this to your .emacs file, and then evaluating it  .

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path (list "/usr/local/bin")))
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using the exec-path-from-shell package on OSX : https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell